# Convert TeraData query to Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

Please convert the below TeraData query to Hive..I am new to Hive and not able to convert it..
Please let guide how to convert Case .. When of teradata into Hive.
While converting..I am getting lot of errors

```
SELECT 

MLOC.MATL_LOC_ID,
MLOC.MATL_ID,
MLOC.LOC_PRTY_ID,
MLOC.SRC_SYS_CD,
MLOC.PLNT_CD,
MLOC.PRCTR_SGMNT_ID,
MLOC.PRCTR_CD,
MLOC.CC_SGMNT_ID,
MLOC.CC_CD,
MLOC.CNTL_AREA_NUM,
MLOC.DFLT_MATL_PLNT_DESC,
MLOC.VALUATION_CATEGORY_CD,
MLOC.DMND_PLNT_CD,
MLOC.SFTY_STK_QTY,
MLOC.MATL_ABC_CLSN_CD MATL_ABC_CLSN_CD_ORIG,

  case when (MATL_ABC_CLSN_CD is null or trim(MATL_ABC_CLSN_CD)='' or MATL_ABC_CLSN_CD='#') then  'NOT DEFINED' 
   when MATL_ABC_CLSN_CD not in ('A','B','C','D','Z') then 'C'
  else MATL_ABC_CLSN_CD end MATL_ABC_CLSN_CD_DERV,

       case when src_sys_cd in ('M07','M02','M09','M18','M22','M25','M27') and MATL_ABC_CLSN_CD_DERV = 'A' then '98%' 
   when src_sys_cd in ('M07','M02','M09','M18','M22','M25','M27') and MATL_ABC_CLSN_CD_DERV in ('B','C','D','Z') then '96%' 

   when src_sys_cd in ('M17','M03','M21') and MATL_ABC_CLSN_CD_DERV = 'A' then '99%' 
   when src_sys_cd in ('M17','M03','M21') and MATL_ABC_CLSN_CD_DERV in ('B','C','D') then '98%' 

      when src_sys_cd in ('M01','M10') and MATL_ABC_CLSN_CD_DERV = 'A' then '99%' 
   when src_sys_cd in ('M01','M10') and MATL_ABC_CLSN_CD_DERV in ('B','C','D') then '97%' 

   when src_sys_cd in ('M26','M29') and MATL_ABC_CLSN_CD_DERV = 'A' then '96%' 
   when src_sys_cd in ('M26','M29') and MATL_ABC_CLSN_CD_DERV in ('B','C','D') then '94%' 

   else 'NOT DEFINED' end ITEM_SERV_LVL_TGT,

   ((MLOC.SFTY_STK_QTY * MAU.FACT_NUMRTR_MEAS) / MAU.FACT_DENOM_MEAS) AS "SFTY_STK_QTY_IN_EACHES", 
   REPLENISHMENT_LEAD_DAY_CNT,
REPLENISHMENT_PRCS_CD

FROM SCMAIN_V.MATL_LOC MLOC

LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
SELECT
MATL_ID, BASE_UOM_CD , ALT_UOM_CD,FACT_NUMRTR_MEAS,FACT_DENOM_MEAS,FINANCIAL_SYSTEM_ID
FROM
SCMAIN_V.MATL_ALT_UOM
WHERE ALT_UOM_CD = 'EA'
AND TRIM(SRC_SYS_CD) LIKE 'M%'
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY 
MATL_ID, BASE_UOM_CD
ORDER BY DAI_UPDT_DTTM DESC, FACT_DENOM_MEAS ASC)=1
) MAU 
ON MLOC.MATL_ID = MAU.MATL_ID  
AND MLOC.BASE_UOM_CD = MAU.BASE_UOM_CD 

WHERE MLOC.SYS_VLD_TO_DT = TIMESTAMP '9999-12-31 00:00:00' 

);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to rewrite the  '**QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(...)**' operation as **'SELECT ROW_NUMBER OVER(...) WHERE ROWNUM='** operation in your inner query since hive is not yet supporting the usage of QUALIFY

rest all query looks fine from hive point of view including CASE. 
Another minor issue is the usage of double quotes at "SFTY_STK_QTY_IN_EACHES".

Here is the altered query you can try with:

```
SELECT 
MLOC.MATL_LOC_ID,
MLOC.MATL_ID,
MLOC.LOC_PRTY_ID,
MLOC.SRC_SYS_CD,
MLOC.PLNT_CD,
MLOC.PRCTR_SGMNT_ID,
MLOC.PRCTR_CD,
MLOC.CC_SGMNT_ID,
MLOC.CC_CD,
MLOC.CNTL_AREA_NUM,
MLOC.DFLT_MATL_PLNT_DESC,
MLOC.VALUATION_CATEGORY_CD,
MLOC.DMND_PLNT_CD,
MLOC.SFTY_STK_QTY,
MLOC.MATL_ABC_CLSN_CD MATL_ABC_CLSN_CD_ORIG,

  case when (MATL_ABC_CLSN_CD is null or trim(MATL_ABC_CLSN_CD)='' or MATL_ABC_CLSN_CD='#') then  'NOT DEFINED' 
   when MATL_ABC_CLSN_CD not in ('A','B','C','D','Z') then 'C'
  else MATL_ABC_CLSN_CD end MATL_ABC_CLSN_CD_DERV,

       case when src_sys_cd in ('M07','M02','M09','M18','M22','M25','M27') and MATL_ABC_CLSN_CD_DERV = 'A' then '98%' 
   when src_sys_cd in ('M07','M02','M09','M18','M22','M25','M27') and MATL_ABC_CLSN_CD_DERV in ('B','C','D','Z') then '96%' 

   when src_sys_cd in ('M17','M03','M21') and MATL_ABC_CLSN_CD_DERV = 'A' then '99%' 
   when src_sys_cd in ('M17','M03','M21') and MATL_ABC_CLSN_CD_DERV in ('B','C','D') then '98%' 

      when src_sys_cd in ('M01','M10') and MATL_ABC_CLSN_CD_DERV = 'A' then '99%' 
   when src_sys_cd in ('M01','M10') and MATL_ABC_CLSN_CD_DERV in ('B','C','D') then '97%' 

   when src_sys_cd in ('M26','M29') and MATL_ABC_CLSN_CD_DERV = 'A' then '96%' 
   when src_sys_cd in ('M26','M29') and MATL_ABC_CLSN_CD_DERV in ('B','C','D') then '94%' 

   else 'NOT DEFINED' end ITEM_SERV_LVL_TGT,

   ((MLOC.SFTY_STK_QTY * MAU.FACT_NUMRTR_MEAS) / MAU.FACT_DENOM_MEAS) AS SFTY_STK_QTY_IN_EACHES, 
   REPLENISHMENT_LEAD_DAY_CNT,
REPLENISHMENT_PRCS_CD

FROM SCMAIN_V.MATL_LOC MLOC

LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
SELECT
T.MATL_ID, T.BASE_UOM_CD , T.ALT_UOM_CD,T.FACT_NUMRTR_MEAS,T.FACT_DENOM_MEAS,T.FINANCIAL_SYSTEM_ID
FROM
(
SELECT 
 MATL_ID, BASE_UOM_CD , ALT_UOM_CD,FACT_NUMRTR_MEAS,FACT_DENOM_MEAS,FINANCIAL_SYSTEM_ID,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY 
 MATL_ID, BASE_UOM_CD
 ORDER BY DAI_UPDT_DTTM DESC, FACT_DENOM_MEAS ASC) as ROWNUM FROM 
 SCMAIN_V.MATL_ALT_UOM
 WHERE ALT_UOM_CD = 'EA'
 AND TRIM(SRC_SYS_CD) LIKE 'M%'
) T
 WHERE T.ROWNUM=1
) MAU 
ON MLOC.MATL_ID = MAU.MATL_ID  
AND MLOC.BASE_UOM_CD = MAU.BASE_UOM_CD 

WHERE MLOC.SYS_VLD_TO_DT = TIMESTAMP '9999-12-31 00:00:00';
```

Note:
 I have validated this query in my environment , i got the  Synamtic excpetion due to 'table not found'and did not get any syntax errors 
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Addy for your great help,

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps (link from other forum)

https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/516/help-converting-teradata-sql-to-hive.html